# Add tmsu tags as a helm-source

Tags: helm, tags

How can I add [tmsu](https://tmsu.org/) tags as a source for `helm-mini`?

**Edit**

There doesn't seem to be such a source, so I am trying to define it by myself consider something like this:

```
(helm :sources (helm-build-async-source "test2"
                 :candidates-process
                 (lambda ()
                   (start-process "tmsu" nil "tmsu" "files" "tag1 tag2")))
      :buffer "*helm async source*")
```

However this doesn't work, since now it is hard coded to call tmsu for the tags tag1 and tag2. Instead helm should update the candidate list dynamically if I change the tmsu query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the input from `helm-pattern`, for example,

```
(helm :sources
      (helm-build-async-source "test"
        :candidates-process
        (lambda ()
          (start-process "echo" nil "echo" helm-pattern))))
```